# AngularJs: Directive NEVER called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I have a directive that spontaneously stopped working. For some reason, it **is never called** with no error prints out in the console. This is odd because **other directives** (which *seem* virtually identical) **are working** (see the very end of the post for a working directive).

This is the **directive**:

```
angular.module('popup').directive('popup', ['Locator', 'PopupService', // This line of code is reached
    function(Locator, PopupService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                "show": '=',
                "anchor": '=',
                'direction': '='
            },
            link: function($scope, element, attr) { // This never called
                $scope.$watch('show', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue) { // This is never called
                        var pos = Locator.getCenterPosition($($scope.anchor));
                        PopupService.togglePopup($(element), {
                            x: pos.x,
                            y: pos.y,
                            origin: $scope.direction,
                            remove_callback: function() {
                                $scope.show = false;
                                console.log("SHOW: " + $scope.show);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        autoHide();
                    }
                }, true);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

This is the Jade code including the directive (Jade is an **html** templating language.):

```
block total-content
  .div {{ edit }}
  .main-body(ng-controller="editEditorController" ng-init="popups = {};format.colorMode='W'; draftID='#{draftID}'; draftEditorID='#{draftEditorID}'; draftOwnerID='#{draftOwnerID}' ")
    div {{ commentEditor }}
    ul#left-tool-list.side-tool-list.tool-list()
      li#comments-tool-box
        span.tool-box-title Comments
        span.tool-box-control-area
          #tool-box-controls
            span#comment-button.tool-box-button(ng-click="newComment()") Add Comment
            span#view-comments-button.tool-box-button(ng-init="popups.showCommentPopup = false" ng-click="popups.showCommentPopup = true; $event.stopPropogation();" stop-event='click') View Comments
          div#comment-list-container(popup show="popups.showCommentPopup" anchor="'#view-comments-button'" direction="'top'") // The directive in question
            comment-displayer#comment-list(edit="edit")
```

This is the declaration for the **app**:

```
var editEditorApp = angular.module('editEditorApp', ['general', 'API', 'popup']);
```

And this is the **order of the includes**:

```
  /* App */   script(src='/js/angular/editEditor/editEditorApp.js')
  /* JQuery */   script(src='/js/pxem.JQuery.js')
  /* Plain JS */   script(src='/styles/js/window-height.js')
  /* Tinymce */   script(src='/js/ice_tinymce/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js')
  /* JQuery dep. */   script(src='/js/jquery.browser.min.js')
  /* Angular Module - factory */   script(src='/js/angular/api/api.js')
  /* Angular Module - directives */   script(src='/js/angular/directives/general.js')
  /* Angular Module - popup (services) */   script(src='/js/angular/general/popupService.js')
  /* Angular Module - popup (directive) */   script(src='/js/angular/directives/popup.js')
  /* Angular Module */   script(src='/js/angular/filter/cut.js')
  /* Angular Module - factory */   script(src='/js/angular/editEditor/commentLikeCreator.js')
  /* Angular Module - factory */   script(src='/js/angular/editEditor/autoSave.js')
  /* Angular Module - directives */   script(src='/js/angular/editEditor/commentBox.js')
  /* Angular Module - directives */   script(src='/js/angular/editEditor/editor.js')
```

**This directive is working**, but I don't know why it is:

```
editEditorApp.directive('commentBox',
    function(PopupService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: "/partials/edit-comment-box",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                "comment": '=',
                "onDelete": '=',
                "onHide": '=',
                "location": '=',
                "show": '='
            },
            link: function($scope, element, attr) {
                console.log("LINK POPUP");
                $scope.$watch('show', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log("NEW VALUE: " + newValue);
                    if (newValue) {
                        console.log("SHOW!");
                        $scope.popup = PopupService.popPopup($(element), {
                            x: location.x,
                            y: location.y,
                            origin: 'bottom',
                            hideOthers: true,
                            remove_callback: function() {
                                $scope.show = false;
                                console.log("SHOW: " + $scope.show);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        if ($scope.popup) {
                            $scope.popup.removePopup();
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                console.log("CONTROLLER");
                $scope.delete = function() {
                    $scope.popup.removePopup();
                    if ($scope.onDelete) {
                        $scope.onDelete();
                    }
                };
                $scope.hide = function() {
                    $scope.popup.removePopup();
                    if ($scope.onHide) {
                        $scope.onHide();
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
);
```

**Note:** This problem was previously posted under a different question, but I realize now that it wasn't the "watch" part of the directive that was broken, but that the directive was never called. I deleted the aforementioned question and posted this one.

Comment: Does the console report anything, in for example Google Chrome's Dev Tools (F12)?

Comment: @stevuu Sorry I wasn't clear. When I said "no error" I meant that no error was reported in the console.

Comment: You don't reference `ng-app` anywhere, could you include the complete HTML?

Comment: @user1066946 The template uses inheritance and Jade variables to declare the ng-app, so it's very confusing to post. Ng-app is definitely working properly, as other directives on the page are working.

Comment: I'm just a noob to this, but can you prove it's the directive and not the watch?  Like if you watch "show" in the controller, and alter it by binding a control to it, will that watch work?

Comment: @someShmuck I removed all of my debugging code (console.log, etc.) to make it easier to read, but yes, that's how I figured out it's not being called. The file is definitely included, but the `link` function is never called. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: @someShmuck In the code, there are comments next to the lines I know were called and that I know were not called, in place of the console.log debugging code.

Comment: The best thing to do is to look at the compiled html that jade created first, then you'll see if there are any differences. What you have shown here is not clear enough. Especially if you are sure it worked before, it must be something else that changed it. I presume you are using version control? If so, just revert back to the version that worked and take it from there.

Comment: Have you tried to change the name ie module('popup').directive('mypopup'

Comment: @Whisher No. I will now, but why would that work?

Comment: may be the module name and the directive name conflict

Comment: @Wisher Thanks, but no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: You surely have tried disabling the restrict: 'A' ?

Comment: @Nik I did try that (I tried almost everything I could think of), but it didn't work.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my asking such basics questions: In the popup.js in the directives directory, you are sure it is loaded, like tested with a console.log('hi') -- Also, i see you have a popupservice.js, there's no chance that that module's name is also "popup" is there? -- lastly, can you isolate and require only popup directive to see if it works?

Comment: @Nik Yes, it's definitely loaded (I've done exactly what you mentioned). The module name for popupservice.js is also "popup," but it doesn't declare a new module, it extends the old one. I'm sure of that because I've put them in the same file (and same module) with the same error. Thanks for any suggestions you can give.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. How about all the following: naming? If naming didn't do anything how about just give it a dummy Hello World directive to see if it renders; and whether it's called by <popup>, <div popup> <div ng-popup> and etc was the matter. also the version of angular?

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm having the same problem when testing some directives with Jasmine. Identical ones work just fine. Is it some sort of failing dependency?

Comment: Are you using minified script files in your environment?

Comment: Which file declares the popup module that is shared by the directive and the service?  `angular.module('popup')` will find the existing module but `angular.module('popup', [])` is needed first to declare it.  If that form is used later it will overwrite the original module with no warning.

Comment: @BBZ I did get it working, but I can't remember how. I just looked back through the code, but everything's changes so much since then (I only started version control recently). Wish I could be more help.

Comment: find lookman's answer below... did you define angular.module('popup',[]) somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

Notice the difference you use your module in the first one and your declaration and usage of module in the second one.

In the first one where it is not working, you are not putting any dependencies. Even you do not have any, just put an empty array.

```js
angular.module('popup',[]).directive('popup', ['Locator', 'PopupService', // This line of code is reached
    function(Locator, PopupService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                "show": '=',
                "anchor": '=',
                'direction': '='
            },
            link: function($scope, element, attr) { // This never called
                $scope.$watch('show', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue) { // This is never called
                        var pos = Locator.getCenterPosition($($scope.anchor));
                        PopupService.togglePopup($(element), {
                            x: pos.x,
                            y: pos.y,
                            origin: $scope.direction,
                            remove_callback: function() {
                                $scope.show = false;
                                console.log("SHOW: " + $scope.show);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        autoHide();
                    }
                }, true);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not yet a complete answer and will be updated if more information is given. But, a few things that help me in such cases:

- According your list of includes you don't include angular yet. Add angular as include if it's missing.
- There is no code that changes the watched `show` variable to anything that evaluates to true. Make your code change the `show` variable to get `if(newValue)` executed.

If the previous points do solve the problem, here some suggestions on how to narrow down the problem:

- The working directive is included in the same module `editEditorApp`, whereas the non-working directive is included in another module, that is dependency injected. Try declaring the directive on `editEditorApp`.
- The directive is called like the module, AFAIK this should be no problem, but it could not hurt to try to rename it.

This answer is a work in progress for a better answer you need to narrow down the problem to a **reproducible example**, i.e. all code is available. Otherwise everything remains guesswork! So far this answer is meant as:

> Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer.

as the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) suggest.

Comment: Yes. I'm really interested in the Jade output actually. I do not think anything severe is wrong with the actual directive.

(Also, am I the only one actually finding the Jade code more confusing than actual HTML?)

Comment: While many of these are good suggestions, none of them qualify as answer. I understand that you are trying to earn a bounty, buy the answer section is for **ANSWERS** not questions or good suggestions. Those go into **Comments** section.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DaveA This is the best answer I can give based on the information provided. As you see I am waiting for the author to clarify the question and will definitely improve my answer. Still I think it is providing information already. I change the wording to make that more clear...

Comment: @eitanfar This not a critique and only partly a request of clarification. It's mainly the best answer I can give right now - see also my response to dave.

Comment: You are absolutely right that OP left out some pertinent info. But as a result you seem to be guessing. Maybe this, if not, it looks like that -- maybe this. That's specifically what the **Comment** section is for. Asking pertinent questions and giving suggestions. Bounties make all of us want to rush to accomodate, but lack of good material doesn't make your list anything more than good guesses / suggestions. PS, god use of the quote but it's too vague to mean much.

Answer (score 1):

1) Put jQuery above AngularJS

so that the sequence is as below

```
/* JQuery */     script(src='/js/pxem.JQuery.js')   
/* AngularJS *   script(src='<angularjs cdn>')   
/* App */        script(src='/js/angular/editEditor/editEditorApp.js')
```

AngularJS bundles jQlite with it but if you put jQuery it will use your jQuery.

2) As others have pointed out and I got burnt with this before myself:-
Change

```
angular.module('popup')
```

to

```
angular.module('popup',[])
```