# AngularJS: Working directive not called when split to new file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Question**: Why isn't my (previously working) AngularJS directive being called after splitting a module into separate files?

**Background**: I had my `postcards` module contained in a single file. I am trying, unsuccessfully, to split it. The `postcards.factories` and `postcards.controllers` file are working fine. I cannot get the single directive in `postcards.directives` to function. I have been successful at doing exactly this with a different, far more complex module.

**Research**: I have read through a couple SO posts, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100169/angularjs-directive-never-called) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151391/angular-directive-not-being-called) without much luck. Those posts seems to focus on the initial declaration of the `module` without the required `[]`.

**Main Module** - **postcards**

```
var postcardsApp = angular.module('postcards', ['postcards.directives', 'postcards.factories', 'postcards.controllers']);
```

**postcards.directives**

```
var postcardAppDirectives = angular.module('postcards.directives', ['postcards.controllers']);

postcardAppDirectives.directive('numPostcards', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        template: '{{ ctrl.numPostcards }}',
        controller: 'postcardDirectiveController as ctrl'
    }
});
```

**postcards.controllers**

```
var PostcardsControllers = angular.module('postcards.controllers', ['postcards.factories']);

PostcardsControllers.controller("postcardDirectiveController", ['PostcardFactory',
    function (PostcardFactory) {
        var _this = this;
        PostcardFactory.getNumPostcards().$promise.then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            _this.numPostcards = data['numPostcards'];
        });
    }]);

// This controller works fine.
PostcardsControllers.controller('PostcardMainController', ['PostcardFactory', function (PostcardFactory) {...}
```

**postcards.factories**

```
// These are retrieving data fine.
var POSTCARD_URL = 'http://' + BASEURL + '/api/v1/postcards/';

var PostcardsFactories = angular.module('postcards.factories', []);

PostcardsFactories.factory('Inbox', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(POSTCARD_URL);
}
]);

// More factories pulling data from my API here...

PostcardsFactories.factory('PostcardFactory', ['$http', 'Inbox', 'Sent', 'PostcardDetail', 'NewPostcard', 'UnreadCount', '$q',
    function ($http, Inbox, Sent, PostcardDetail, NewPostcard, UnreadCount, $q) {

        var PostcardFactory = {}

        // Get count of all unread messages sent TO a member
        PostcardFactory.getNumPostcards = function () {
            return UnreadCount.query()
        };

        ...  // Tons of stuff in here

        return PostcardFactory
    }
```

**Main App var** - To show that `postcards` is included as a dependency

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngResource', 'boat', 'members', 'location', 'trips',
    'angular-jwt', 'tools', 'carousel', 'navbar', 'dashboard', 'postcards', 'widgets', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router']);
```

**HTML calling the directive**

```
<li ng-if="navCtrl.isLoggedIn()">
    <a ui-sref="dashboard.postcards">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="color: dodgerblue"></span>
    <span style="margin-left: -3px; margin-top: -15px; background-color: red; opacity: .75;" class="badge">
    <num-messages></num-messages>
    </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**Included in HTML file**

```
<script src="./static/app/postcards/postcards.js"></script>
<script src="./static/app/postcards/postcards_factories.js"></script>
<script src="./static/app/postcards/postcards_controllers.js"></script>
<script src="./static/app/postcards/postcards_directives.js"></script>
```

**Question Restatement**: Why isn't my directive being called?

**Additional Question**: I don't really grok when I need to include other modules as part of the `.module('myModule', [...])` declaration.

Comment: Not seeing any HTML here so I'm not sure why you think your directive would be *called* at all. Assuming that there is in fact some HTML with `<num-postcards></num-postcards>` or similar, have you included all the above files in `<script>` tags and added the `postcards` module as a dependency in your main application module, eg `angular.module('myApp', ['postcards'])`?

Comment: Yes - a clear omission on my part, apologies. The HTML remained the same, calling the directive as an element exactly as you have in your comment. The file is loaded, and the main app is a dependency exactly as you have in your profile. I'll edit to add those things.

Comment: So no errors in your console? Do you see the log entry for `console.log(data)` in your `postcardDirectiveController`? Only other thing I'd recommend is using a `link` function in your directive instead of a controller. Directive controllers are really only for *directive-to-directive* communication

Comment: Also, where do the `PostcardDetail`, `NewPostcard` and `UnreadCount` services come from? You should probably add their modules as dependencies in `postcards.factories` module

Comment: There are no console errors. `PostcardDetail` and others are defined within `postcards.factories` thusly: `PostcardsFactories.factory('UnreadCount', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(POSTCARD_URL + 'unread');
}
]);`. They pull data from my Django backend. The resources are working with my controllers. It is important to note that the directive in question works perfectly when the module is contained within a single file. Something about splitting this up is causing it **not to be called**. The obvious answer is that I didn't import, but that doesn't seem to be true...

Comment: Have a look in your browser's *Sources* developer console (that's what it's called in Chrome anyway). Make sure all the appropriate files are loaded and most importantly that their contents is what you expect. Also, make sure you clear cache, etc and reload the page.

Comment: Cache cleared, page reloaded. Under Sources in the Chrome dev console I have all four postcards(_xxx).js files, and they are up to date.

Comment: Umm, just noticed your HTML uses `<num-messages>` but your directive is `numPostcards`. It should be `<num-postcards></num-postcards>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered - in the stupidest way possible.

`<num-messages></num-messages>` was not refactored by a colleague to reflect the directive's name change to `numPostcards`. I did not check it.

Now being called successfully with `<num-postcards></num-postcards>`.

Sorry, @Phil.